# Passing Information from Java (Servlet) to CGI method?

Tags: java, servlets, cgi

I have this java servlet that grabs information from a form, I need to then take that information and pass it to a specific method in an .exe program and get the value that method returns.

Is there a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by ".exe program" you mean a DLL, you could use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to call methods in it from Java.

This is non-trivial but doable.

Comment: Thanks, worked out well!

for anyone else who comes by this i found this very helpful: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this in one of my projects, but we were on Linux and not Windows. Here is a general blueprint for how to go about doing it.

You will need to:

1. Setup your .exe CGI file as an
   external process using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filename, env)`
2. Setup references to your input stream and error stream in your external process.

   ```
   InputStream fromCgi = p.getInputStream();
   InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
   ```
3. Then you copy the bytes from your external process input stream into your servlet output stream.

   ```
   IOUtils.copy(fromCgi, response.getOutputStream()); //using apache commons io
   ```

Note: There is a lot of glue that needs to be put between all of the parts, but that is the general strategy of how to wrap CGI in a Servlet.